# Why am I getting 504 errors on homestead with new Laravel projects

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, vagrant, homestead

I have about 6 projects in my homestead box currently. They all work fine. Today, I went to do a tutorial and created a new project, ran the default migrations, did both mappings in my homestead.yaml and added an entry on my hosts file. For whatever reason, I am getting 504 gateway timeouts. Any ideas what to try?

```
folders:
- map: ~/Development/Web/Name1
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name1

- map: ~/Development/Web/Name2
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name2

- map: ~/Development/Web/Name3
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name3

- map: ~/Development/Web/Name4
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name4

- map: ~/Development/Web/Name5
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name5

- map: ~/Development/Web/Name6
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name6

- map: ~/Development/Web/Name7
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name7

- map: ~/Development/Web/VuePhp
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/VuePhp

sites:
- map: name1.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name1/public

- map: name2.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name2/public

- map: name3.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name3/public

- map: name4.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name4/public

- map: name5.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name5/public

- map: name6.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name6/public

- map: name7.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/Name7/public

- map: vuephp.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Development/Web/VuePhp/public
```

VuePhp is the entry that's causing the issue

Edit: suddenly, it has started redirecting vuephp.dev:8000 to the Name1 site. Still no idea.

Comment: have you set you nginx block up or checked its there, also your local host file for vuephp.dev, normally if your pointing to the server but it get another site, then the gnigix domain block is missing or incorrect, also restarting nginx etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-provisioning using vagrant reload --provision did the trick.